# Aforge.net работа с потоком видео

Tags: c#, .net, clr, aforge

в программе камера должна отображать всё происходящее в режиме онлайн без записи информации, для этого использую библиотеки AForge.Video и AForge.Video.DirectShow от Aforge.net. При просмотре диспетчера задач заметил, что при включенной камере приложение начинает есть память до определённого момента(так понимаю, накапливаются снимки с потока), потом память сбрасывается, видимо CLR, затем опять всё по новой.
А теперь вопрос: как подчищать накопленную информацию с потока самостоятельно без помощи CLR?
Пример кода:

```
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = null;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }


    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
```

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы информация поступала "насквозь" не сохраняясь где-то, как в случае с работой камеры на телефоне, когда просто её включаешь и наводишь на что-нибудь, или как при настройке камеры в скайпе, к примеру: она работает (ты себя видишь), но информация просто отобразилась и "ушла"

Answer (score 1):

Выделение памяти в управляемых платформах дёшево, очистка – дорога. Поэтому пока свободная память есть, она потребляется. Как её станет мало, просыпается сборщик мусора и очищает её. Поэтому то, что вы видите в диспетчере задач – нормальное поведение.

Вообще, не стоит вмешиваться в работу системы управления памятью (сборщика мусора) в .NET. Однако, если очень хочется, то можно вызывать метод [`GC.Collect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Кроме потребления памяти (которой много), более остро стоит вопрос потребления неуправляемых ресурсов (которых мало), таких как хендлы. Стоит позаботиться о своевременном их освобождении.

В вашем коде это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

    this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
}
```

Особо отмечу, что вызов `Dispose` в общем случае не освобождает память, он освобождает ресурсы (хендлы)!

P. S. Исходное изображение `Frame` тоже нужно диспозить. Так как оно клонируется, я предполагаю, что оно используется где-то ещё. После окончания использования вызывайте `Dispose`. А может, клонирование и не нужно?

Comment: Событие videoSource_NewFrame само диспозит Image после возврата из обработчика, поэтому клонирование нужно. (Дух поднял вопрос)