# Ошибка при выводе видео с usb камеры

Tags: c#, usb, камера, web-camera, aforge

Пытаюсь вывести изображение с камеры на экран. Использую библиотеку Aforge. Перенёс рекомендуемый код в свой проект.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ToolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        toolStripButton1.Click += ToolStripButton1_Click;
        toolStripButton2.Click += ToolStripButton2_Click;
    }

    FilterInfoCollection fic = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    VideoCaptureDevice vcd;

    private void ToolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcd.Stop();
    }

    private void ToolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcd.NewFrame += Vcd_NewFrame;
        vcd.Start();
    }

    private void Vcd_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }

    private void ToolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcd = new VideoCaptureDevice(fic[toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < fic.Count; i++)
        {
            toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(fic[i].Name);
        }
    }
```

При запуске видео-потока возникает следующая ошибка "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'panel1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан." picturebox1 лежит на panel1.

Частично проблему решает вот такой код в событии нового кадра, но тогда программа закрывается с ошибкой и не выгружается процесс.

```
   if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
             this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                }));
       else
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```

выпадает вот такая ошибка: System.ObjectDisposedException: "Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен. Имя объекта: "Form1"." На строке

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => {                     
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();                     
}));
```

В обработчике закрытия формы у меня вот так:

```
if (vcd.IsRunning) vcd.SignalToStop();
```

В предыдущих проектах этот код работал без каких-либо проблем.
Что может вызывать эту ошибку?
Какие ещё  c# библиотеки можно использовать для вывода видео с юсб камеры?

Comment: Какая ошибка-то? Приведите её.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651460/184217 - Ресурсы нужно освобождать

Comment: Ошибка возникает в этой строке `pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();`  в обработчике события нового кадра. "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'panel1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Comment: Нет. Эту ошибку вы исправили с помощью `Invoke`. После этого с какой ошибкой программа закрывается?

Comment: Так всё-таки: `panel1` или `pictureBox1`? Вероятно, вы не к одному контролу обращаетесь из другого потока. Все такие вызовы оберните в `Invoke`.

Comment: При завершении с использованием Invoke выпадает вот такая ошибка: System.ObjectDisposedException: "Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен.
Имя объекта: "Form1"."
На строке `this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                    }));`

Comment: В обработчике закрытия формы у меня вот так: 
            `if (vcd.IsRunning) vcd.SignalToStop();`

Comment: picturebox1 лежит на panel1

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Всю необходимую информацию поместите в вопрос, отредактировав его.

Comment: В обработчике закрытия формы отписывайтесь от события `Vcd_NewFrame`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Опять выдаёт ошибку System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object." да еще и по не русски заговорил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В библиотеке Aforge.Controls есть специальный контрол videoSourcePlayer для вывода видео. Заменив picturBox на него и приделав к нему VideoSourceDevice, всё замечательно заработало как надо безо всяких Invoke и заморочек с потоками.

запуск видео потока:

```
     vcd = new VideoCaptureDevice(fic[selectedCamId].MonikerString);
    
     videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = vcd;
    
     vcd.Start();
```

И всё же я уверен, что раньше это работало через событие нового кадра.

Comment: А ведь мама говорила: "Читай документацию, сынок".

Comment: Код в вопросе у вас не работает, потому что вы не отписываетесь от событий при закрытии формы. Форма закрылась, контролы (пикчабокс) уничтожились, а класс AForge продолжает к нему обращаться.

Comment: Чтобы быстро выяснить, почему раньше работало, а сейчас нет, достаточно взять прошлый код из системы контроля версий и сравнить с нынешним (сделать diff). Подозреваю, что вы не используете систему контроля версий (git). Ну так пора начать.